# screencast support in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

I know there're some really wonderful tools out there for capturing screen in motion on a desktop but as part of development of this app I've been working on, I need to capture activities taking place on a particular widget area. The development so far has been done entirely on top of open Qt SDK but I don't see any support for screencast as such.

I've already explored all the relevant answers on this forum in addition to googling. Merging together periodic pixmaps on grabWidget seems to be one way to go but I'm hoping for something more elegant and robust. All the howTos I found are based on top of DirectX or GDI.

Please let me know the proper way if there exists one in this context or the other alternatives I have in GPL license frame.

Comment: I'm not an expert, so I won't post this as an answer: but you should look into the Qt Testing framework as it might be supported there.  The testing framework allows for GUI testing of Qt apps, so...  maybe?  (it's supposed to be quite good).

Comment: doing grabWidget is the way I'd do it. This allows you to adjust the framerate quite easily as well as do any processing before it gets shown. Its quite efficient (i've done a grabWindow screencapture server to udp client viewer) and relatively straightforward...

Comment: ok that does help lay off concerns about investing time in at least exploring it and I guess there's no way to be sure until I try it out. While I was hoping for an authoritative _answer_ to the topic, still appreciate the responses. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

since no one put up another answer, i'm putting my comment as an answer here..

doing [grabWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qpixmap.html#grabWidget-2) is the way I'd do it. This allows you to adjust the framerate quite easily as well as do any processing before it gets shown.

Its quite efficient (i've done a grabWindow screencapture server to udp client viewer) and relatively straightforward...